# Subset of segments with monotonically increasing or decreasing slopes

Tags: geometry

I'm currently working on a paper and can not figure out how to prove a relatively simple statement of the author.

Let $S$ be a set of disjoint segments in the plane of size $n$, which are stabbed by a vertical line $\ell$ (i.e. $\ell$ intersects every segment in $S$). All segments are in general position, meaning they are neither vertical nor do any segment endpoints share their x-coordinates.

Now sort the segments in $S$ by the y-coordinate of their intersection with the line $\ell$. 
The authors define a subset $Q \subseteq S$ to be the **maximum** subset of segments that have monotonically **increasing or decreasing** slopes. Afterward, they state that by the Erdös-Szkeres theorem, $|Q| \geq \sqrt{n}$. I could not figure out the relation between the intersection point's y-coordinate and the slope of the segments. Can someone help me with the proof?

Comment: There's no relationship. It's just a direct application of pigeonhole principle (A standard problem if you have seen it used before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot a scatter plot of "y-coordinate against slope".

By Erdos-Szkeres, applied to $r, s = \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil $, since $n \geq ( \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil - 1 )^2 + 1 $, there is a subsequence of length $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ that is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: I had that thought too. Doesn't this interpretation imply that we can find a polygonal path of at least $\lfloor{\sqrt{n-1}}\rfloor$ (instead of $\lfloor {\sqrt{n}} \rfloor$) edges with same sign slopes within that scatter plot?

Comment: Fixed, Was playing around with the inequalities to get that result.